# Implementing Yolov3 model with Octave Convolutions instead of 2D Convolutions

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo

I am trying to implement (or rather modify) Yolov3 to use Octave Convolution instead of 2D Convolution. My intent is to make the model faster. My current implementation of the model is taken from [Yolov3 model with 2D Convolutions](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/blob/master/ML/Pytorch/object_detection/YOLOv3/model.py). I am following this thesis to introduce Octave Convolution in Yolov3: [Thesis about implementing Yolov3 with Octave Convolutions](https://ruor.uottawa.ca/bitstream/10393/42790/1/Chen_Meihong_2021_thesis.pdf). The implementation described in the thesis does not specify the input and output channels for each layer in the Yolov3 model and I can't understand how they obtained the feature maps at three scales that they describe as:

```
The output of our backbone is composed of feature maps of three scales. 
The size of large-scale feature maps is (256, h/8 , w/8 ). The size of the medium-scale feature maps is (512, h/16, w/16 ). And the size of small-scale features map is (1024, h/32, w/32 ).
```

I am not interesed in the last Octave Convolution layer they use to combine the low and high frequency maps. I want to know how i should setup the input and output channels of my model. Do they perhaps use the last Octave Convolution layer for each scale to get the right number of output channels for the three scales output feature maps?

Can someone help me out by providing me with more details about how this could be implemented? With my current understanding, I have written the 2 Octave Convolution layers they use. These two are described poorly in section 4.3.1 of the thesis. I have implemented the first Octave Convolution layer as:

```
class OctConvL1(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    This module implements the OctConv paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05049v1.pdf
    """
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True, alpha_in=0.125, alpha_out=0.125):
        super(OctConvL1, self).__init__()
        self.alpha_in, self.alpha_out, self.kernel_size = alpha_in, alpha_out, kernel_size

        self.convL = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels,
                                    int(alpha_out * out_channels),
                                    kernel_size, stride, padding=padding, bias=bias)
        self.convH = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels,
                                    out_channels - int(alpha_out * out_channels),
                                    kernel_size, stride, padding=padding, bias=bias)

        self.upsample = torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        # self.avg_pool = partial(torch.nn.functional.avg_pool2d, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=kernel_size)
        self.avg_pool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2,)

    def forward(self, x):
        xl = self.avg_pool(x)
        lf = self.convL(xl)
        hf = self.convH(x)
        return hf, lf
```

The first Octave Convolution layer as I understood is used to create the initial low and high-frequency feature maps. Then they use the second Octave Convolution layer for the rest of the architecture:

```
class OctConvL2(torch.nn.Module):
    """
    This module implements the OctConv paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.05049v1.pdf
    """
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, bias=True, alpha_in=0.125, alpha_out=0.125):
        super(OctConvL2, self).__init__()
        self.alpha_in, self.alpha_out, self.kernel_size = alpha_in, alpha_out, kernel_size
        self.H2H, self.L2L, self.H2L, self.L2H = None, None, None, None
        if not (alpha_in == 0.0 and alpha_out == 0.0):
            self.L2L = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(alpha_in * in_channels),
                                       int(alpha_out * out_channels),
                                       kernel_size, stride, padding=padding, bias=bias)
        if not (alpha_in == 0.0 and alpha_out == 1.0):
            self.L2H = torch.nn.Conv2d(int(alpha_in * in_channels),
                                       out_channels - int(alpha_out * out_channels),
                                       kernel_size, stride, padding=padding, bias=bias)
        if not (alpha_in == 1.0 and alpha_out == 0.0):
            self.H2L = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels - int(alpha_in * in_channels),
                                       int(alpha_out * out_channels),
                                       kernel_size, stride, padding=padding, bias=bias)
        if not (alpha_in == 1.0 and alpha_out == 1.0):
            self.H2H = torch.nn.Conv2d(in_channels - int(alpha_in * in_channels),
                                       out_channels - int(alpha_out * out_channels),
                                       kernel_size, stride, padding=padding, bias=bias)
        self.upsample = torch.nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='nearest')
        self.avg_pool = partial(torch.nn.functional.avg_pool2d, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=kernel_size)
        # self.avg_pool = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2,)

    def forward(self, x):
        hf, lf = x
        h2h, l2l, h2l, l2h = None, None, None, None
        if self.H2H is not None:
            h2h = self.H2H(hf)
        if self.L2L is not None:
            l2l = self.L2L(lf)
        if self.H2L is not None:
            h2l = self.H2L(self.avg_pool(hf))
        if self.L2H is not None:
            l2h = self.upsample(self.L2H(lf))
        hf_, lf_ = 0, 0
        for i in [h2h, l2h]:
            if i is not None:
                hf_ = hf_ + i
        for i in [l2l, h2l]:
            if i is not None:
                lf_ = lf_ + i
        return hf_, lf_
```

I have also created two CNNBlocks:

```
class CNNBlockL1(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0, bn_act=True, alpha_in=0.125, alpha_out=0.125):
        super(CNNBlockL1, self).__init__()
        self.use_bn_act = bn_act

        self.conv = OctConvL1(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, not bn_act, alpha_in, alpha_out)
        self.bn_h = None if alpha_out == 1 else nn.BatchNorm2d(int(out_channels * (1 - alpha_out)))
        self.bn_l = None if alpha_out == 0 else nn.BatchNorm2d(int(out_channels * alpha_out))
        self.act = nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1, inplace=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.use_bn_act:
            x_h, x_l = self.conv(x)
            x_h = self.act(self.bn_h(x_h))
            x_l = self.act(self.bn_l(x_l)) if x_l is not None else None
            return x_h, x_l
        else:
            x_h, x_l = self.conv(x)
            return x_h, x_l

class CNNBlockL2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride=1, padding=0, bn_act=True, alpha_in=0.125, alpha_out=0.125):
        super(CNNBlockL2, self).__init__()
        self.use_bn_act = bn_act

        self.conv = OctConvL2(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, not bn_act, alpha_in, alpha_out)
        self.bn_h = None if alpha_out == 1 else nn.BatchNorm2d(int(out_channels * (1 - alpha_out)))
        self.bn_l = None if alpha_out == 0 else nn.BatchNorm2d(int(out_channels * alpha_out))
        self.act = nn.LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.1, inplace=True)

    def forward(self, x):
        if self.use_bn_act:
            x_h, x_l = self.conv(x)
            x_h = self.act(self.bn_h(x_h))
            x_l = self.act(self.bn_l(x_l)) if x_l is not None else None
            return x_h, x_l
        else:
            x_h, x_l = self.conv(x)
            return x_h, x_l
```

````
My upsampling layer is:

    class UpsampleBlock(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, scale_factor=2):
            super(UpsampleBlock, self).__init__()
            self.ups = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=scale_factor)
    
        def forward(self, x):
            return self.ups(x[0]), self.ups(x[1]) if x[1] is not None else None

My residual block becomes like this:

    class ResidualBlock(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, channels, use_residual=True, num_repeats=1):
            super().__init__()
            self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
            for repeat in range(num_repeats):
                self.layers += [
                    nn.Sequential(
                        CNNBlockL2(channels, channels // 2, kernel_size=1),
                        CNNBlockL2(channels // 2, channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
                    )
                ]
    
            self.use_residual = use_residual
            self.num_repeats = num_repeats
    
        def forward(self, x):
            for layer in self.layers:
                if self.use_residual:
                    h_f, l_f = layer(x)
                    x = (x[0] + h_f, x[1] + l_f)
                else:
                    x = layer(x)
    
            return x

The model becomes like:

      class YOLOv3(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, in_channels=3, num_classes=7):
            super().__init__()
            self.num_classes = num_classes
            self.in_channels = in_channels
            self.layers = self._create_conv_layers()
    
            # self.downsample = nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=2)
    
        def forward(self, x):
            outputs = []  # for each scale
            route_connections = []
            for layer in self.layers:
                if isinstance(layer, ScalePrediction):
                    outputs.append(layer(x))
                    continue
    
                x = layer(x)
    
                if isinstance(layer, ResidualBlock) and layer.num_repeats == 8:
                    route_connections.append(x)
    
                elif isinstance(layer, UpsampleBlock):
                    x = (torch.cat([x[0], route_connections[-1][0]], dim=1), torch.cat([x[1], route_connections[-1][1]], dim=1))
                    route_connections.pop()
    
            return outputs
    
        def _create_conv_layers(self):
            layers = nn.ModuleList()
            in_channels = self.in_channels
            a0=True
    
            for module in config:
                if isinstance(module, tuple):
                    out_channels, kernel_size, stride = module
                    if not a0:
                        layers.append(
                            CNNBlockL2(
                                in_channels,
                                out_channels,
                                kernel_size=kernel_size,
                                stride=stride,
                                padding=1 if kernel_size == 3 else 0,
                            )
                        )
    
                    else:
                        layers.append(
                            CNNBlockL1(
                                in_channels,
                                out_channels,
                                kernel_size=1,
                                stride=1,
                                padding=1
                            )
                        )
                        a0 = False
                    in_channels = out_channels
    
                elif isinstance(module, list):
                    num_repeats = module[1]
                    layers.append(ResidualBlock(in_channels, num_repeats=num_repeats,))
    
                elif isinstance(module, str):
                    if module == "S":
                        layers += [
                            ResidualBlock(in_channels, use_residual=False, num_repeats=1),
                            CNNBlockL2(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=in_channels // 2, kernel_size=1),
                            ScalePrediction(in_channels // 2, num_classes=self.num_classes),
                        ]
                        in_channels = in_channels // 2
    
                    elif module == "U":
                        layers.append(UpsampleBlock(scale_factor=2),)
                        in_channels = in_channels * 3
    
            return layers

For the config of the model i have used the orginal configuration: 

```.
""" 
Information about architecture config:
Tuple is structured by (filters, kernel_size, stride) 
Every conv is a same convolution. 
List is structured by "B" indicating a residual block followed by the number of repeats
"S" is for scale prediction block and computing the yolo loss
"U" is for upsampling the feature map and concatenating with a previous layer
"""
config = [
    (32, 3, 1),
    (64, 3, 2),
    ["B", 1],
    (128, 3, 2),
    ["B", 2],
    (256, 3, 2),
    ["B", 8],
    (512, 3, 2),
    ["B", 8],
    (1024, 3, 2),
    ["B", 4],  # To this point is Darknet-53
    (512, 1, 1),
    (1024, 3, 1),
    "S",
    (256, 1, 1),
    "U",
    (256, 1, 1),
    (512, 3, 1),
    "S",
    (128, 1, 1),
    "U",
    (128, 1, 1),
    (256, 3, 1),
    "S",
]
````

I have tried to modify the Yolov3 implementation of [Yolov3 with 2D Conv](https://github.com/aladdinpersson/Machine-Learning-Collection/blob/master/ML/Pytorch/object_detection/YOLOv3/model.py) to use Octave Convolution instead of 2D Convolution by following [this thesis](https://ruor.uottawa.ca/bitstream/10393/42790/1/Chen_Meihong_2021_thesis.pdf). I have managed to implement the Octave Convolution blocks described in the thesis but i am unsure of their implementation and i do not know what number of input and output channels i should use i should use in each layer of the architecture.

Comment: What is an “Octave Convolution”? — Found this: https://paperswithcode.com/method/octave-convolution — Damn, these DL people keep reinventing the wheel and giving it stupid names.

Comment: @CrisLuengo What do you mean by "keep reinventing the wheel"? You can know more about Octave Convolution by reading the paper [Drop an Octave: Reducing Spatial Redundancy in Convolutional Neural Networks with Octave Convolution](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05049)

Comment: They keep “reinventing the wheel” because they reinvent stuff that’s been around for decades in the field of image processing. The only new thing about “octave convolution” is the name.

Comment: What do you think they "reinvented" in this case? I think research is about inventing/improving based on stuff already known.

Comment: They reinvented [pyramids](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)). “Octave Convolution” is just a convolution of each level of the pyramid. I just looked at the paper you linked, which makes things way more complicated than they are, of course. It seems the authors don’t understand the frequency domain representation or what a convolution does. What they refer to a “inter-frequency communication” cannot happen in a convolution. A convolution can only change the strength and phase of a frequency component, it cannot change its frequency.

Comment: I’ve become jaded reading DL/CNN papers. I tend to reject review request for them, but sometimes I end up doing one of these reviews, and end up having to explain to the authors basic things about math notation, and image processing fundamentals. It is frustrating.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. I think with “inter-frequency communication” they mean they combine (by adding up the resulting features from the pathways they talk about) the information from the features HL and HF. Anyway i am not interested in applying this type of convolution to Yolov3 to improve its speed by maintaining its accuracy.

Comment: I know what they meant. What I’m saying is that, if the frequency separation is implemented correctly, those components should be 0. There should be no information flow from “L” to “H” or back.

Comment: @Cris Luengo I see. Can you offer me some help regarding the integration of this type of convolution in Yolov3 (or suggest me another type of conv that maintains the ap while increasing the speed?)? I have figured out that I do not have to change the input and output number of channels in DarkNet53.  My problem now is that when I am at the last residual block "["B", 4]" the "low-frequency" feature maps are of the size (9,9), and as such when h2h and l2h are added up h2h has size a size of (19,19) while l2h has a size of (18,18). This problem is not even mentioned in the thesis I linked sadly.